# How can I write a query that looks in all array entries?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How do I write a CosmosDB query or SPR that allows me to look for an entry in all entries in an array? where each array entry is a complex datatype and not just a simple array?

I have tried using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.locales[0].categories[0] AS topLevelCategory 
FROM c 
WHERE c.locales[0].country = 'SE'
```

The problem is that I cannot gurantee that c.loclales[0] is always 'SE' some times that is the second or third entry in the array so I dont know what c.locales[X] should be where X represents the locale I need, for example if c.locales[0] is 'SE' then I wont get the hit I want because 'SE' happens to be c.locales[1]

How can get around this limitation? I need to be able to first apply the country = 'SE' to get the correct array entry and then after that get the categories from that array entry.

I just cannot figure out how this can be done?

Sample document below and expected output would be 
"Herr" in whatever output format is easiest.

```
{
    "id": "0570eca0-8f16-4c85-a985-e3a271bcc6bc",
    "_id": "5b07c2bfbc7407000122e8b4",
    "artno": "0614460008",
    "vendor": "Acme",
    "updatedAt": "2019-06-25T18:50:33.167Z",
    "locales": [
        {
            "title": "Gestreiftes T-Shirt",
            "description": "Gestreiftes T-Shirt aus Baumwolljersey.",
            "categories": [
                "Herren",
                "Große Größen",
                "T-Shirts & Tanktops",
                "T-Shirt"
            ],
            "brand": null,
            "images": [
                ],
            "country": "DE",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "language": "de",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008005",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008002",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "S",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008004",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "L",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XS",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008006",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XXL",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008003",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "M",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Striped T-shirt",
            "description": "Striped T-shirt in cotton jersey.",
            "categories": [
                "Men",
                "T-shirts & Vests",
                "Short Sleeve",
                "T-shirt"
            ],
            "brand": null,
            "images": [
                   ],
            "country": "UK",
            "currency": "GBP",
            "language": "en",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008006",
                    "urls": [
                        ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XXL",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008005",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008004",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "L",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008002",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "S",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008003",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "M",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XS",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Randig t-shirt",
            "description": "En randig t-shirt i bomullstrikå.",
            "categories": [
                "Herr",
                "T-shirts & Linnen",
                "Kortärmat",
                "T-shirt"
            ],
            "brand": null,
            "images": [
                 ],
            "country": "SE",
            "currency": "SEK",
            "language": "sv",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XS",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "S",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XXL",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "M",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "L",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Striped T-shirt",
            "description": "Striped T-shirt in cotton jersey.",
            "categories": [
                "Men",
                "T-shirts & Tank tops",
                "Short Sleeves",
                "T-shirt"
            ],
            "brand": null,
            "images": [
                  ],
            "country": "US",
            "currency": "USD",
            "language": "en",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "S",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "M",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "L",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XXL",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XS",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "relatedArtno": [
        "0614460001",
        "0614460002",
        "0614460005",
        "0614460006",
        "0614460007",
        "0614460011",
        "0614460012"
    ],
    "_rid": "QEwcAMCVWqgGAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/QEwcAA==/colls/QEwcAMCVWqg=/docs/QEwcAMCVWqgGAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"2e00f1ca-0000-0c00-0000-5d144d660000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1561611622
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Join` in your sql:

```
SELECT locales.categories[0] AS topLevelCategory 
FROM c 
join locales in c.locales
WHERE locales.country = 'SE'
```

Output:

[image]

---

Update Answer:

Two points.

One,your locales is also an array so you can't access categories with `c.locales.categories`.You need to query categories using `c.locales[index].categories`.

Two,Array_contains has third param. If you want to filter array with partial conditions,you need to add third param as false.

```
ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.locales[index].categories[0], 'kids',true)
```

More details,please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-system-functions#bk_array_contains).

[image]

Comment: This seems to work but when I want to verify I dont get any hits for the following query.

SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.locales.categories[0], 'kids')

Where kids is returned from the original query as a topLevelCategory, I would expect the result of my verification query to list all products where the Categories array has 'kids' in position 0 , why do I get 0 hits on that?

Comment: But then I end up in the same problem again since I dont know the index? So how do I know what index to put ? or can I again use a join to only get the part of the array I want? I am sorry but its really difficult to get my head around this query structures

Comment: I tried using this with index from 0 up to 10 and still get no hit, so I must be missing something here.

SELECT c.id FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.locales[5].categories[0], 'kids', true)

Since kids is returned in the original as topLevelCategory reason dictates it must show up when I hit the correct locales index right? but not matter how high I go I get nothing, Basically I am trying to query "Show me all products where the topLevelCategory = 'XX' where XX comes from the initial query

Comment: @MattDouhan Of course the array_contains sql is not suitable for your requirement.You still need to use the join sql to filter columns in the array like my original answer.

Comment: But i can’t get it to work when I want all documents where the Category[0] matches XX where XX would be any of the ones returned from the original query